# Clearing a value when an option is selected from a drop down menu in Excel (VBA)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

Good Morning,

I'm trying to write a code in VBA, that while selecting from a drop down menu from D2, it will clear any value from E2 and F2 without removing the formatting.

I have tried the follow good but for some reason I'm not being able to get any results.

```
   Option Explicit
     Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D")) Is Nothing Then
             If Target.Address = "$D$2" Then
             Range("E:F" & Target.Row).ClearContents
             End If
         End If
      End Sub
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean by not getting any result?

Comment: it means that if I select an option from the drop down menu, the corresponding columns are not clearing the texts within them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
   Option Explicit
     Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D2")) Is Nothing Then
             Range("E" & Target.Row & ":F" & Target.Row).ClearContents
        End If
      End Sub
```

Or, if you want to check things for other rows, then maybe

```
   Option Explicit
     Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D")) Is Nothing Then
             If Target.Row = 2 Then
                Range("E" & Target.Row & ":F" & Target.Row).ClearContents
             End If
             If Target.Row = 4 Then
                ' do some other stuff
             End If
         End If
      End Sub
```

Comment: Edit: This worked perfectly.  Thank you very much :)